# existence of a contraction of sin(x) on $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: lipschitz-functions, numerical-calculus, contraction-operator

I tried to  proof whether a contraction  with sin(x) on $D=[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ can happen. It seems that there exists no contraction  because the contraction constant  L leads to $L=max\rvert f'\lvert=1$.
Are you guys agree with this result?

Best regards,
gui

Comment: Correct, since $|\sin'(0)| = 1$, the smallest Lispchitz rank is one hence it cannot be a contraction. However, you can show that $x_{n+1} = \sin x_n$ will converge to $0$.

Comment: This exactly was the reason where I am getting confused.If one plot the sin(x)=x one can see that there exists a fixed poin,isn't it?but Banach theorem  restricted  it and says :No,you cannot use fixed point to get solutions!

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. It is not a contraction. That does not mean it does not have a fixed point.

Comment: Okay,I thought Banach where strong enough to  give me the right answer in this context.Which Theorem could show me the right answer  ?And how I decide which theorem is the right one?

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. The contraction mapping theorem does not apply here.

Comment: So,there exist no fixed point iteration?

Comment: Again, I do not understand what you are asking. My first comment was that $x_{n+1} = \sin x_n$ converges to $0$, which is the only fixed point of $\sin$. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Which theorem leads to this result?

Comment: I don't know if there is an explicit theorem, but it is straightforward to see that $x_n$ is monotonic and bounded hence has a limit $x$. Since $\sin$ is continuous, we must have $x = \sin x$ and the only solution to this is $x=0$, hence $x_n \to 0$.

Comment: So one condition of the function  violates the  Banach otherwise one gets a fixed point existence  result.Do you know which condition it should be?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Yes,it is the contraction one.Sorry for wasting your time .But I would  to thank you for your explanations!

Comment: No problem, glad to be able to help.